# how to make global variable for select box slelected text in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am displaying  select query in select box  it's displaying fine . now my think 
to make an global varibale which text i have selected to next page

Comment: ...Can you try rephrasing that?  I'm afraid I don't quite understand what you're asking.

Comment: Put it into the $_SESSION

Comment: $query = "SELECT brand FROM boxno";

  $result = mysql_query($query);

  print "<SELECT name=item>";
  while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  foreach ($line as $value)
  {
  // If the selected ID matches the current row, then mark it as selected.
  $Selected = ($Selected_ID == $value) ? " selected='selected'" : '';       
  print "<OPTION$Selected value='$value'";
  $_SESSION['value'] = $Selected;
  } 
  print ">$value</OPTION>";

Comment: i want to call this selected text in next page how?

Comment: You are missing `}`. Please post the code into question so that we can understand easily

Comment: show your tried code\

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you pass selected text to next page via `url` as a parameter. You can get it on the next page with `$_GET['']`.